# Sharepoint 2010 SPImport.Run security exception

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010

I want to use SPExport (which is working OK) and SPImport to copy one web to another location. I am using Application Page in Sharepoint Foundation 2010. This code is executed on a Button click event.

```
using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb(sourceWebUrl))
                    {
                        SPExportSettings exportSettings = new SPExportSettings();
                        exportSettings.FileLocation = exportPath;
                        exportSettings.BaseFileName = exportFileName;
                        exportSettings.SiteUrl = site.Url;

                        exportSettings.ExportMethod = SPExportMethodType.ExportAll;
                        exportSettings.FileCompression = true;
                        exportSettings.IncludeVersions = SPIncludeVersions.All;
                        exportSettings.IncludeSecurity = SPIncludeSecurity.All;
                        exportSettings.ExcludeDependencies = false;
                        exportSettings.ExportFrontEndFileStreams = true;
                        exportSettings.OverwriteExistingDataFile = true;

                        SPExportObject expObj = new SPExportObject();
                        expObj.IncludeDescendants = SPIncludeDescendants.All;
                        expObj.Id = web.ID;
                        expObj.Type = SPDeploymentObjectType.Web;
                        exportSettings.ExportObjects.Add(expObj);

                        SPExport export = new SPExport(exportSettings);
                        export.Run();
                    }
 using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb(destinationWebUrl))
                    {
                        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

                        SPImportSettings importSettings = new SPImportSettings();

                        web.FileLocation = exportPath;
                        web.BaseFileName = exportFileName;
                        web.IncludeSecurity = SPIncludeSecurity.All;
                        web.UpdateVersions = SPUpdateVersions.Overwrite;
                        web.RetainObjectIdentity = false;
                        web.SiteUrl = site.Url;
                        web.WebUrl = web.Url;
                        web.Validate();

                        SPImport import = new SPImport(importSettings);
                        import.Run();
                        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                    }
```

Exception "The security validation for this page is invalid. Click Back in your Web browser, refresh the page, and try your operation again. " is thrown when SPImport.Run() is called.

I haven't been able to find a solution for this problem neither adding FormDigest control on application page nor Allowing Unsafe Updates on the destination web.

Also, running this code from Console Application works OK, but if code runs from Application Page it is not working (even with elevated security).

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to do this by adding

```
SPUtility.ValidateFormDigest();
```

at line 1.

Comment: Congrats on the solution.  When you are able, please make sure to mark your answer as 'accepted' so that others might learn from your success.  Cheers~

Comment: For people who are elevating privileges, you need to do this before. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.sputility.validateformdigest(v=office.14).aspx